# How I can edit a Web reference in NET 2010?

Tags: vb.net, edit, web-reference

I manually added a web reference and I need to edit it but I see no option to do that.
When I add a service reference is possible to edit some options, but I can see how to do that when is a web reference.
Is it possible or I must to delete the actual web reference and add a new one?

Comment: Webservice settings are stored in your web.config.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't find that file, but I found App.config and disabled expect100Continue and now works ok.